# SSL connections to Redis instance for socket-io adapter

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

How to connect to remote redis instance with `rediss://` scheme using [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) module?

And another issue is I need to enter the credential to authenticate but this module ignore `username` (for redis instance that has only a password works fine).

Answer (score 0):

I create `pub` and `sub` redis client because I can't figure it out how to provide correct credential to [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) adapter without [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) module that including `username` and it seems doesn't support `rediss://` scheme by itself.

```
const redis = require("redis");
const socket = require('socket.io');
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
const URL = require('url').URL;

const io = socket(httpServer, socketOption);
const connectionString = "rediss://admin:password@private-redis-xxxx.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061"

const pub = redis.createClient(connectionString, { tls: { servername: new URL(connectionString).hostname } });
const sub = redis.createClient(connectionString, { tls: { servername: new URL(connectionString).hostname } });

io.adapter(redisAdapter({ pubClient: pub, subClient: sub }));
```